# Using WP POD magic link as a variable

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using PODs plugin in Wordpress and using their magic tags in a POD template. I need to set a magic tag as a variable IE `$branchdownload = '{@resource_link_protected}';` so the I can use it in a if statement such as `if( get_the_title() == $branchdownload  ){...}`

This doesn't seem to work, I assume because the tag is called rather than the actual value, so is there away to set the magic tag as a permanent variable so it can be used in various PHP scripts ?